# Unable to submit app for distribution (Titanium)

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have set up the relevant certifications and app , however when I build it for iTunes it will always build a development version of the app. I have tried to change the certification by doing this:

Titanium iOS device - > Manage configuration but I am unable to select my production certification.

Any idea on how publish it for the app store through Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solutions, click on "App explorer" tab in titanium then you should see an icon which says "Publish", press that and you can then build the application using the distribution profile.